# Declaring an object variable makes all the previous instructions slower

Tags: c++, class, constructor, sparse-matrix, stdvector

I ran into a fastidious problem and I have no idea of what is causing it. I hope you can help me find a solution.

**Framework**: I implemented a sparse_matrix class using the CSR representation and I used this object as the basis for a recommendation system. The class is defined as follows:

```
class sparse_matrix_csr
{
    public:
        sparse_matrix_csr();
        sparse_matrix_csr(const std::vector<int> &row_indices);
        sparse_matrix_csr(const std::vector<int> &row_indices, const size_t nb_columns);

        // other member functions omitted

    private:
        std::vector<int> _row_indices;
        std::vector<int> _row_start_indices;
        std::vector<int> _column_indices;
        std::vector<double> _values;
        bool _column_sorted_by_index;
};
```

The `_row_indices` vector contains the indices of the rows of the matrix. `_row_start_indices` contains the index of the first element of a given row in the `_column_indices`, which contains the column indices, and `_values` vector, which contains the elements of the matrix. In particular, the constructor `sparse_matrix_csr(const std::vector<int> &row_indices, const size_t nb_columns)` is implemented as follows:

```
sparse_matrix_csr::sparse_matrix_csr(const std::vector<int> &row_indices,
                                     const size_t nb_columns):
    _row_indices(row_indices),
    _row_start_indices(row_indices.size()),
    _column_indices(row_indices.size() * nb_columns, 0),
    _values(row_indices.size() * nb_columns, 0.0),
    _column_sorted_by_index(true)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < _row_start_indices.size(); ++i)
        _row_start_indices[i] = i * nb_columns;
}
```

This constructor takes in the indices of the rows of the sparse matrix and the number of elements that will be contained in each row. In fact, in the application I am considering, I have same matrices that are sparse only wrt the rows.

**Problem**: The algorithm is structured as follows

```
\\ Instruction block 1
{
    \\ Do something 
}

sparse_matrix_csr mat(list_indices, nb_columns); 

\\ Instruction block 2
{
    \\ Do something
}
```

If I run the first block of instructions alone (commenting out all that follows), my algorithm runs smoothly. However, if I uncomment the second part of the algorithm, the first part of the algorithm slows down a lot. I have been able to identify the critical line for this slow-down in the declaration of `mat`. However, I cannot explain this retro-action on the first part of the algorithm. The full algorithm is reported at the end of my question.

**My considerations**: I have never observed such a retro-action and therefore I am a little confused. One possibility that I have considered is that I have a problem in memory management which causes the slow-down of the previous part of the algorithm. I am currently working on some matrices that have around 2e6 elements, i.e. around 4e6 values stored in 2 vectors. I read on another post on stack overflow that the data contained in a std::vector are allocated in the heap. Is that always true? even if I initialize a vector with a given size as I do in the sparse matrix constructors above?

If you need some clarification, do not hesitate!

Thanks in advance, 
Pierpaolo

---

Full algorithm:

```
void collaborative_filtering_mpi (std::string ratings_file, std::string targets_file,
                                  std::string output_file, int k_neighbors, double shrinkage_factor,
                                  bool output_debug_data)
{
    std::cout << "COLLABORATIVE FILTERING ALGORITHM - k = " << k_neighbors
              << " , d = " << shrinkage_factor << std::endl;
    stopwatch sw_total;
    sw_total.start();

//-------------------------------------
// STEP 1: Read data from input files
//-------------------------------------

std::cout << "1) Read input files: ";
stopwatch sw;
sw.start();

//-------------------------------
// 1.1) Read user rating matrix
//-------------------------------

// Initialization
sparse_matrix_csr user_item_rating_matrix(ratings_file, true, true, true); // file is sorted, skip header

//-------------------------------------------------
// 1.2) Read targets (user, item) to be predicted
//-------------------------------------------------

// Initialization
sparse_matrix_csr targets(targets_file, true, false, false); // do not read ratings column

sw.stop();
double time_input = sw.get_duration();
std::cout <<  time_input << std::endl;

//-----------------------------------------
// STEP 2: Pre-computations
//-----------------------------------------

std::cout << "2) Pre-computations: ";
sw.start();

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
// 2.1) Sort user_item_rating_matrixand compute relevant sizes of the problem
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

// Sort: if file is sorted, sort should do nothing.
user_item_rating_matrix.sort_columns_by_index();

// Compute list of users and list of items
std::vector<int> list_users;
user_item_rating_matrix.rows(list_users);
std::vector<int> list_items;
user_item_rating_matrix.columns(list_items);

// [DEBUG]: print user_rating_matrix
if (output_debug_data)
{
    std::ofstream ofs_debug("data_debug/debug_user_rating_matrix.txt");
    ofs_debug << user_item_rating_matrix;
    ofs_debug.close();
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------
// 2.2) Compute inverse user rating matrix (indexed by column)
//-------------------------------------------------------------

// Initialize item_user_rating_matrix:  it is a sparse matrix with
// items on the rows, users on the columns and rating as values.
// This variable will be helpful when computing similarities.
sparse_matrix_csr item_user_rating_matrix;

// Compute item_user_rating<_matrix by transposing the user_rating_matrix
transpose (user_item_rating_matrix, item_user_rating_matrix);

// [DEBUG]: print item_user_matrix_on_file
if (output_debug_data)
{
    std::ofstream ofs_debug("data_debug/debug_item_user_matrix.txt");
    ofs_debug << item_user_rating_matrix;
    ofs_debug.close();
}

//-----------------------------------------------
// 2.3) sort targets and compute relevant sizes
//-----------------------------------------------

// Compute list of target items
std::vector<int> list_target_items;
targets.columns(list_target_items);

// [DEBUG]: print targets
if (output_debug_data)
{
    std::ofstream ofs_debug("data_debug/debug_targets.txt");
    ofs_debug << targets;
    ofs_debug.close();
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
// 2.4) Compute difference between list_items and list_targets
//--------------------------------------------------------------

std::vector<int> list_non_target_items;
compute_difference_vector (list_items, list_target_items, list_non_target_items);

// [DEBUG]
if (output_debug_data)
{
    std::ofstream ofs_debug("data_debug/debug_difference_vector.txt");

    ofs_debug << "list_items - size: " << list_items.size() << std::endl;
    for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator iter = list_items.begin(); iter != list_items.end(); ++iter)
        ofs_debug << (*iter) << ",";
    ofs_debug << std::endl << std::endl;

    ofs_debug << "list_target_items - size: " << list_target_items.size() << std::endl;
    for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator iter = list_target_items.begin(); iter != list_target_items.end(); ++iter)
        ofs_debug << (*iter) << ",";
    ofs_debug << std::endl << std::endl;

    ofs_debug << "list_non_target_items - size: " << list_non_target_items.size() << std::endl;
    for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator iter = list_non_target_items.begin(); iter != list_non_target_items.end(); ++iter)
        ofs_debug << (*iter) << ",";
    ofs_debug << std::endl << std::endl;

    ofs_debug.close();
}

//--------------------------------------------
// 2.5) Compute average rating for each user
//--------------------------------------------

dictionary<int, double> average_rating_vector;
compute_average_rating(user_item_rating_matrix, average_rating_vector);

if (output_debug_data)
{
    std::ofstream ofs_debug("data_debug/debug_average_rating_vector.txt");
    for (dictionary<int, double>::const_iterator iter = average_rating_vector.begin();
         iter != average_rating_vector.end(); ++iter)
        ofs_debug << (*iter).get_key() << ": " << (*iter).get_value() << std::endl;
    ofs_debug.close();
}

sw.stop();
std::cout << sw.get_duration() << std::endl;

//-------------------------------------
// STEP 3: Similarity matrix
//-------------------------------------

std::cout << "3) Compute similarity matrix: ";
sw.start();

// Initialize similarity_matrix with target items on the rows.
sparse_matrix_csr similarity_matrix(list_target_items,
                                    list_target_items.size() + list_non_target_items.size());

// compute similarity matrix
compute_similarity_matrix_mpi(similarity_matrix,
                              item_user_rating_matrix,
                              average_rating_vector,
                              list_target_items,
                              list_non_target_items,
                              shrinkage_factor);

// [DEBUG]: print similarity matrix sorted by similarity
if (output_debug_data)
{
    std::ofstream ofs("data_debug/debug_similarity_matrix.txt");
    ofs << similarity_matrix;
    ofs.close();
}

sw.stop();
std::cout << sw.get_duration() << std::endl;

//---------------------------------------------------------------
// STEP 4: Find top-K similar elements with positive similarity
//---------------------------------------------------------------

std::cout << "4) Find top-K similar elements:" << std::endl;
sw.start();

if (k_neighbors > 0)
{
    //---------------------------------------------------
    // 4.1) Sort similarity matrix by rating (row-wise)
    //---------------------------------------------------

    std::cout << "   .... Sort similarity matrix by rating: ";
    sw.start();

    // Sort all the rows of the similarity_matrix by similarity.
    // If two items have the same rating, sort them in descending order of item.
    //similarity_matrix.sort_columns_by_value();
    similarity_matrix.sort_columns_by_value();

    // [DEBUG]: print similarity matrix sorted by similarity
    if (output_debug_data)
    {
        std::ofstream ofs ("data_debug/debug_similarity_matrix_sorted_by_rating.txt");
        ofs << similarity_matrix;
        ofs.close();
    }

    sw.stop();
    std::cout << sw.get_duration() << std::endl;

    //--------------------------------------------------------
    // 4.2) Cut the useless columns of the similarity matrix
    //--------------------------------------------------------

    std::cout << "   .... Reduce similarity matrix: ";
    sw.start();

    sparse_matrix_csr similarity_matrix_reduced(list_target_items,
                                                k_neighbors);

    reduce_similarity_matrix_mpi (similarity_matrix,
                                  similarity_matrix_reduced,
                                  k_neighbors);

    // [DEBUG]: print similarity matrix sorted by similarity
    if (output_debug_data)
    {
        std::ofstream ofs ("data_debug/debug_similarity_matrix_reduced.txt");
        ofs << similarity_matrix_reduced;
        ofs.close();
    }

    sw.stop();
    std::cout << sw.get_duration() << std::endl;

    //---------------------------------------------------
    // 4.3) Sort the reduced similarity matrix by items
    //---------------------------------------------------

    std::cout << "   .... Sort similarity matrix by index: ";
    sw.start();

    // Sort all the rows of the similarity_matrix by index.
    similarity_matrix_reduced.sort_columns_by_index();

    // [DEBUG]: print similarity matrix sorted by similarity
    if (output_debug_data)
    {
        std::ofstream ofs ("data_debug/debug_similarity_matrix_sorted.txt");
        ofs << similarity_matrix_reduced;
        ofs.close();
    }

    sw.stop();
    std::cout << sw.get_duration() << std::endl;

    //-----------------------------------------
    // STEP 5: Compute predictions for targets
    //-----------------------------------------

    std::cout << "5) Compute predictions: ";
    sw.start();

    compute_predicted_ratings_mpi (targets,
                                   user_item_rating_matrix,
                                   similarity_matrix_reduced);

    sw.stop();
    std::cout << sw.get_duration() << std::endl;
}
else
{
    //---------------------------------------------------
    // 4.3) Sort the reduced similarity matrix by items
    //---------------------------------------------------

    std::cout << "   .... Sort similarity matrix by index: ";
    sw.start();

    // Sort all the rows of the similarity_matrix by index.
    // similarity_matrix.sort_columns_by_index();
    similarity_matrix.sort_columns_by_index();

    // [DEBUG]: print similarity matrix sorted by similarity
    if (output_debug_data)
    {
        std::ofstream ofs ("data_debug/debug_similarity_matrix_sorted.txt");
        ofs << similarity_matrix;
        ofs.close();
    }

    sw.stop();
    std::cout << sw.get_duration() << std::endl;

    //-----------------------------------------
    // STEP 5: Compute predictions for targets
    //-----------------------------------------

    std::cout << "5) Compute predictions: ";
    sw.start();

    compute_predicted_ratings_mpi (targets,
                                   user_item_rating_matrix,
                                   similarity_matrix);

    sw.stop();
    std::cout << sw.get_duration() << std::endl;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------
// STEP 6: Print the prediction matrix in output file
//-----------------------------------------------------

std::cout << "6) Print predictions on file: ";
sw.start();

std::ofstream ofs_output(output_file);
targets.print(ofs_output);

sw.stop();
double time_output = sw.get_duration();
std::cout << time_output << std::endl;

sw_total.stop();
double time_total = sw_total.get_duration();
std::cout << ">> Total computation time: " << time_total << std::endl;
std::cout << ">> Total computation time - no input/output: " << (time_total - time_input - time_output) << std::flush;
}
```

---

**UPDATE - 05 February 2015:** I don't know what happened, but the code is now running fine on my 64-bit machine. However, it is still very slow on a 32-bit VM that I need to use to run my code. I measured the size of a sparse_matrix object using `sizeof` and it occupies 52 bit. I think this might be causing a cache problem (credit goes to @Dark Falcon). Do you have any ideas on how I could solve this problem and make my algorithm run efficiently on the 32-bit VM?

---

**UPDATE - 06 February 2015:** Well, the problem comes and go. I tried to change the implementation of the sparse_matrix_csr class wrapping the data in a `shared_ptr` in the following way:

```
class sparse_matrix_csr
{   
    public: 
        \\ public methods omitted
    private:
        class sparse_matrix_csr_data
            {
                public:
                    sparse_matrix_csr_data() {}
                    sparse_matrix_csr_data(const std::vector<int> &row_indices): _row_indices(row_indices) {}
                    sparse_matrix_csr_data(const std::vector<int> &row_indices, const size_t nb_columns);
                    sparse_matrix_csr_data(const std::string file, bool file_is_sorted, bool skip_header, bool read_values);

                    // data
                    std::vector<int> _row_indices;
                    std::vector<int> _row_start_indices;
                    std::vector<int> _column_indices;
                    std::vector<double> _values;
                    bool _column_sorted_by_index;
            };

        std::shared_ptr<sparse_matrix_csr_data> _data;
};
```

This modification did not improve things. I am currently having problems both on the 32-bit VM and the 64-bit laptop. I have no idea about what is causing the program to be so slow.

Comment: That's a lot of code. Have you tried simplifying it until the problem disappears, to narrow down the possible cause (and have less code for other people to wade through)? Still, thanks for an overall well-structured question, even with comments in code!

Comment: How are you measuring the time of the first block with and without the second part?

Comment: It is very hard to tell how you measured it. I'm not convinced there wasn't a mistake in measuring. That said, did you try allocating it with `new` instead? My guess is that the variable layout in the stack frame is such that when you add that large-ish object, the other locals wind up not all fitting in a cache line. If this is the case, the dynamic code should about as fast as the commented-out version.

Comment: Any chance the declaration uses some outputs from the first section, preventing the compiler from optimizing out some of the computations?

Comment: For measuring the execution time I executed the code until the declaration of `similarity_matrix_reduced` (excluded) with all the following code commented out and I compared it with the execution adding the declaration. Clearly, the compiler might be applying different optimizations in the two cases but I think that this cannot explain such a slow-down (more than x100) of the previous part. Furthermore, the initialization of `similarity_matrix_reduced` is independent on previous data. Finally, shouldn't std::vector be initialized in the heap (even without new)?

Comment: @PierpaoloNecchi: Sure, the data would be dynamic, but the minimum of 8 bytes for the pointer to the data and the size would not be, and you have 4 of them in that object. I don't know how big cache lines are these days, but 64 bytes was common at one time, and that is at least 36 bytes in that object. More on a 64-bit platform.

Comment: @Dark Falcon: I think you might be right. I have another version of the program where I implemented sparse matrices using a "vector-of-vectors" structure and I do not run into this problem. Probably because I only need one pointer for each sparse matrix that I initialize. I am going to see how to implement the class using `new`.

Comment: I opened another question related to this problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28344014/efficient-sparse-matrix-implementation-in-c-for-mpi-parallel-program. I would be grateful if you check it out and share your insights

Comment: Ummm... what compiler and optimization flags do you use?  I saw code examples for which optimizer assigned registers differently between 32 and 64 bit architecture, and on 32bit setting `-O2` actually broke compilation (`-O1` worked ok). Maybe in your case optimization on 32bit actually messes up the 1st part of code. My bet is the optimizer.

Comment: @luk32: I thought about that possibility and tested with and without optimization flags. The problem persists. I think that I have a hidden problem on the first part of the algorithm that always affects the 32-bit version and "sometimes" affects the 64-bit version. As I wrote in the last update, I tried to implement the sparse_matrix class using a smart_pointer to avoid the 4 vectors headers in the cache as it was suggested. This modificiation had no effect on the execution time